# How can I develop/debug the Office 365 Rest Api Notifications NotificationURL?

Tags: office365api, office365-restapi

After testing and research it seems the NotificationURL parameter requires a fully valid SSL certificate or the subscribe call fails.

I am wondering if there is a way I have not found or a clever workaround to use the Office 365 Notifications with a self-signed SSL certificate installed on the NotificationURL during development?

Thanks!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I won't mark this as answered yet in case there is a better way, but here is my work around for the issue.

I created a small webapi project that takes a base64 encoded url as a parameter, ie: https://site.azurewebsites.com/Notify/aHR0cDovL3NvbWVob3N0OjEyMzQ1L05vdGlmeQ==

It proxies the request to that encoded URL and plays back the response.

I hosted this "proxy" as a free azure website making use of the SSL provided and can now subscribe to notifications via my proxy.

It works well enough and means I can work from anywhere.

I'll see if better ideas come along, but if not will accept this as the answer as it seems to work for my development purposes.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). The free version is sufficient to debug WebHooks